# Changing hex color from string's color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I've seen a bunch posted like this but none solved anything for me.

```js
const HexPattern = /(#[0-9a-f]{6})(\s*[\w,]+\s*)/gi

function parseColors(str) {
  return str.replace(HexPattern, (s, g0, g1) => `<span style="color:${g0}">${g1}</span>`)
}
```

If I were to use this code it would replace the text after the hex color in the string with the color but I would want to change the actual hex color string into that color so like if my string was:

```js
let string = "hello there #191919 <-- see that thats black"
```

it would change the #191919 into the hex color represented there and not the text after like my current code does which I found on stackoverflow.

Comment: Exactly what output are you expecting? What is in the string?

Comment: I have a chat which I want when people enter a string which is the message it would display any hex color detected but it would make the part that has the hex color that color unlike the other post it would change the following text in the string mine I want to change the part of the string that contains the hex color to the same text so it would stay the same just the color would be different

Comment: If you show three or four "input" strings, and the matching "output" strings that might help clarify your requirements.

Comment: i'll edit my post

Comment: Try to follow the information on how to create a [mcve] using the snippet option `[<>]` in the edit menu.

Comment: Not going to work well for "this is #FFFFFF" (or whatever matches your background).  You can also change the background, there's an algorithm for determining the best / when to change the background based on the foreground, which you can probably find via google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your question is all in the regex. If you only want to replace the hex colour value in the string with that colour then the second matching group, `(\s*[\w,]+\s*)`, can be removed.

That leaves you with this: `/(#[0-9a-f]{6})/gi`. However it's worth noting that a valid hex colour code can have 3, 6 or 8 characters, so you may also need to cater for that. The example below shows you how to do this:

```js
const hexPattern = /(#[0-9a-f]{8}|#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3})/gi
let parseColors = str => str.replace(hexPattern, (s, match) => `<span style="color:${match}">${match}</span>`);

$('div').html((i, t) => parseColors(t));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Some 3 character hex values: #C00 and #937</div>
<div>Some 6 character hex values: #545234 and #C8929A</div>
<div>Some 8 character hex values: #A63098FF and #00000066</div>
```